# Format the string having quots inside

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I need to build a string *template string "data"*
data is an input. So I prepare a `string format = @"template string ""{0}"""`
but when I do `string.Format(format, "data");`, I get *template string ******data***
I also tried `string format = "template string \"{0}\""`. Had the same problem.
How do I fix the issue?

Comment: Both of those format strings work for me.  Can you post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This works perfect in my case got output `template string "data"` Here is [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SZotGR).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string.Format("\"{0}\"","data");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourInputString = "string";
String output = "template string \"" + yourInputString + "\"";
```

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this one

```
string.Format(@"""{0}""","your string")
```